# Unable to retrieve the used space and free space for the file shares in powershell. I am currently using the below powershell script

Tags: powershell-4.0

```
Function CleanUp-PSDrive {
    Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Where { $_.Name -in (69..90 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ })} | Remove-PSDrive
}

$Csv = Import-Csv "C:\Users\503080876\Documents\New folder\new.txt"

$Csv.Name | ForEach-Object -Begin { $Letter = 69 } {

New-PSDrive -Root  $_ -Name([char]$Letter) -PSProvider FileSystem



  #select root,used | 

 select used,free | export-csv "C:\Users\503080876\Documents\New folder\New1.txt"




    if ($Letter -lt 90) 
    { 
      $Letter++ 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        CleanUp-PSDrive
        $Letter = 69
    }
} -End { CleanUp-PSDrive }
```

Comment: And also when I am exporting as csv, getting only one share drive info not all the shares

Comment: Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function CleanUp-PSDrive {
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Where { $_.Name -in (69..90 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ })} | Remove-PSDrive
```

}

```
$Csv = Import-Csv "path"
```

$Csv.Name | ForEach-Object -Begin { $Letter = 69 } {

new-PSDrive -Root  $_ -Name([char]$Letter) -PSProvider FileSystem -Persist

```
if ($Letter -lt 90) 
{ 
  $Letter++ 
} 
else 
{ 
    CleanUp-PSDrive
    $Letter = 69
}
} -End { CleanUp-PSDrive } |
```

Select-Object   @{name="File Share Name";expression={$*.'DisplayRoot'}}, @{name="Total(GB)";expression={($*.free+$*.used)/1GB}}, @{name="Used(GB)";expression={$*.used/1GB}}, @{name="Free(GB)";expression={$_.free/1GB}}  |

export-csv "path" -NoTypeInformation

Comment: The above code will map all shares and give the file space and used space..                                                   Thanks